# New Google Spreadsheet formula results different than what I see, importrange function unstable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a 200k cell database in New Google sheets. I'm running `QUERY()` in the same spreadsheet but in another sheet.

The results I get from `QUERY()` is perfectly fine. The problem is: when I try to use the resulting queried data in another sheet, the resulting data is not what I see from the `QUERY()`. I only see a portion of it. This happens both when I use `importrange()` and when I use Google app script code to replace `importrange`.

When using code and I `.getValues()` the range, the data fetched is already not what it looks like in the `QUERY` function on the original sheet. So that's why I'm saying the actual result from `QUERY` is different from what I see.

The `QUERY` result from what I see is correct. The data set from `importrange()` or `.getValues()` is incorrect. This just happened suddenly. Before everything was working fine. It started this Friday (March 21, 2014) night EST.

Wondering if anybody else is having this same problem.

Edit: I've also tried the `myimportrange()` custom code provided by ahab as a work around. I get the same result as `importrange()`. I've exhausted what I can try I think. Might be a Google bug?

Edit 3/24/14: It seems to only a problem on formulas. I have a different part of the spreadsheet that was also not importing all of the values, but for that portion i pasted values because it will not change any more, and the problem resolved itself.

It seems like the formula calculates and I can see it but Google's server has a different number for that cell.

edit 3/24/14 10am EST: Things all came back without me doing anything. I think it was a Google issue. They must have turned something off over the weekend and turned it back on when the engineer got into the office today. Should I just delete this question? Moderator?

edit 3/28/14 10pm EST: it's happening again. This time the `QUERY()` function not producing the correct results.

edit 4/2/14: This problem carries over to other formulas (simple formulas)

edit 4/7/14: This seems like a recurring problem over the weekends (US time zone)

edit 4/23/14: latest cycle of `importrange` down started Good Friday, `importrange` works again now.

edit: I have a more accurate description of the error:
So let's say i have a spreadsheet `foo`. In cell `A1`, `sheet1` in spreadsheet `foo`, is a formula that returns value `X`. value `X` is the correct value, but since value `X` depends on all these different calculations (such as a query, which is blank at load) from inside the spreadsheet, when you first open/load the spreadsheet, the initial value is `Y`. Only after about 30 seconds to 1 minute does the value (after calculating what looks like 3-4 times) settle correctly to value `X`. Every time i hit reload on the spreadsheet, the value gets reset to value `Y`, and it takes 30 seconds to 1 minute to arrive at the correct value `X`.

Now i have another spreadsheet `bar`. In `bar`, i'm importing the range `sheet1!A1` from spreadsheet `foo`. However, value `Y` shows up, even though value `X` is displayed in `foo`. So `bar` is only loading the initial value but not the calculated and most recent value `X`.

This phenomena has been ongoing since I started using the new sheets. Sometimes it imports correctly and imports `X` from `foo`, other times it imports `Y` from `foo`. And i've done absolutely nothing. It seems to be unstable. Sometimes it is able to import the correct value, sometimes not.

Comment: You should provide an answer, so that this can be, somehow, be closed and have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem with the sum function. I have a sum formula with a dozen or so values to add. When I click on the cell with the formula, it will display the correct total in the formula bar but the result in the cell displays a previous result. The only way I've been able to correct this glitch is by refreshing the page. Personally, I think this is a ridiculous flaw as it defeats the purpose of having a spreadsheet.